# Paypal Website Payments Pro transaction not getting listed in the Sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have created a simple PHP App for requesting(nvp format) paypal to accept payment from my customers through on-site payment with credit-card, even though when I test it with dummy cards & I get success message in the response, the transaction is not getting listed in my sandbox account "Recent Activity" page or "View all transactions" or "Payments Received".

My Payment type is sale and I am calling "DoDirectPayment" method.

I have already enabled "Payment Pro" for my sandbox account & also the account is "Verified", still transaction entry not getting listed.

Can somebody guide me with a detailed explanation about the issue that might be causing this ?

I am using this as my reference.
https://github.com/GeorgeOld/Paypal-NVP-PHP-code-examples

Comment: tried contacting >paypal? They have support for this kind of issues.

Comment: Sure will do, but I am hoping somebody have encountered this type of issue & have come up with a solution which can make my work lot faster & easier. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: Contacted thier support, but still no response even after 1 day.